# .php file security using MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I have generated a php file that has information stored in a database. To access this a person must use a login in page.

However, when you are using MAMP how can you prevent someone from accessing the file through writing the IP address and php file name e.g. 123.456.78.00:80/fileone.php. I want this fileone.php to be hidden and for them to only access it through a login page.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username'"); //Query the users table if there are matching rows equal to $username
$exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if username exists
$table_users = "";
$table_password = "";
if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing username
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
{
    $table_users = $row['username']; // the first username row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
    $table_password = $row['password']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
    $table_id = $row['id'];
    $page_id = $row['page'];
}
if(($username == $table_users) && ($password == $table_password)) // checks if there are any matching fields
{
        if($password == $table_password)
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username; //set the username in a session. This serves as a global variable
            //echo $table_id;
            //echo $page_id;

            redirect ($page_id); //take the user to the page specified in the users table

        }
    else
    {
        echo "Login Failed";
    }

}
    else
    {
        Print '<script>alert("1. Incorrect Password!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
    }
}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Username!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
    Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
}
function redirect($page_id)
{
/* Redirect browser */    
header('Location: ' . $page_id);
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Login check**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] === true) {
    "Your script"
}
```

If you have a profile for your users, like a normal user = 0 and an admin = 1 you can do it like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] === true && $_SESSION['profile'] == 1) {
    "Your script"
}
```

**Set sessions**

To set set the sessions to true you need this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

    // for set a profile
    $_SESSION['profile'] = 1;
}
```

Maybe I didn't understand you good, but to be sure I will explain something:

You said attached checklogin.php, but you can't use that to deny access for non members. If they know that the file exists, they can type it in the URL and still read fileone.php. The first coding block need to be in your fileone.php.

**Session time**

Search in your php.ini for 'session.gc_maxlifetime'. There will be a number and that is the time in seconds.

Comment: I have attached my checklogin.php. The login page itself doesn't contain much apart from the login button and then redirects the user to this page. I have set a username and password, but this is to check that the user exists in the database and then ensures that they get redirected to their personal page after login. I therefore realise that i need something that will trigger when the user and has logged in and out. How would your code about work to recognise when the user has left, or has been inactive for say 20minutes. Thanks

Comment: yes yes that is very helpful, the section you explained at the bottom is exactly right. That is the problem i have, the fact that they can type the URL and still read the file, so that solution is great. I only have 3 users, their user Id is simple 1,2, and 3. What do you mean by build a profile? All my users have the same editing rights etc. What would i do if i do not have a profile? User ID are stored in the database, and the checklogin.php just makes sure that the username and password match up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rus84 A profile is useful if you have normal users and admins. Normal users aren't allowed to edit the content, but admins are allowed. In your case you can leave it without a profile because everbody with an account may edit

Comment: Thank you for that. Being a newbie to this can i just clarify where to add those comments: The top comment (login check) needs to be added to the top of every .php file (ones that users will be accessing, contains their information), set session code needs to be added in the check login? is that correct? How does the first code prevent someone from accessing the file by typing in the URL? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Rus84 If you read PHP from left to right and from above to the bottom you will get very far!

If they open it on the url they will be checked by the session. Keep in mind 'If(condition is true) { do this } else if ( or are these condition true) { do this } else { do this }' the else statement will always run if there is no condition that is true.